# Instantiating a property that calls on self before super.init() is called

Tags: swift, oop, sprite-kit, instantiation, self

I'm building both `Ship` and also `GenericGun` classes in my first Swift game, and I just ran into a problem instantiating one of `Ships` properties. The property in question, `aGun` calls upon `self` as its value but the error appears because while the property must be set before the call to `super.init()`, the property relies on `self` which can only be accessed *after* `super.init()` is called. I played around a bunch and found that using an optional on the variable makes the error disappear, but I'm not sure why and don't know if it will work long term. Here's my gun class:

```
class genericGun{

    var theShip:Ship
    var theGameScene:GameScene

    init(gameScene:GameScene, shipInstance:Ship){
        theShip = shipInstance
        theGameScene = gameScene
    }

    func addLaser(){
        let aLaser = Laser(laserPosition: theShip.position)
        theShip.lasers.append(aLaser)
    }

    //If statement on user touch to call this
    func shoot(){
        //Pull out the laser from the ship
        let availableLaser = theShip.lasers.removeLast()

        let constY:CGFloat = theShip.position.y
        availableLaser.position = CGPoint(x: theShip.position.x, y:constY)
        //Set its speed
        availableLaser.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 400.0,dy: 0)
        //Add it to the scene
        theGameScene.addChild(availableLaser)

        theShip.canShoot = false
        func printHey(){print("Hey!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")}
        let sayHey = SKAction.runBlock{printHey()}
        let reloadTime = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
        let loadGun = SKAction.sequence([reloadTime, sayHey])

        theShip.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(loadGun))
    }
}
```

The Laser Class:

```
class Laser:SKSpriteNode{

    init(laserPosition:CGPoint){

        let laser = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Sprites/laser.jpg")

        super.init(texture: laser, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: laser.size())

        //Laser physics
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: laser.size().width/2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Laser
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Alien
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0;
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0;
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }   
}
```

The Ship Class:

```
class Ship:SKSpriteNode{

    static var shipState = "norm"

    //A dictionary with String keys and AnyType array values
    static var shipTypes: [String: [Any]] = [

        "norm":[SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/fullShip.png"), SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/laser.jpg"),7],
        "rapid":[SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/fullShip.png"),7],
        "bazooka":[SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/fullShip.png"),7]
    ]

    var moveSpeed:CGFloat
    var lives:Int

    var lasers = [SKSpriteNode]()
    var canShoot = false
    var aGun: genericGun? = nil
    var theGameScene:GameScene

    static var shipImage = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/fullShip.png")//: Int = Int(shipTypes[shipState]![0])

    init(gameScene:GameScene, startPosition startPos:CGPoint, controllerVector:CGVector){

        self.lives = 3
        self.moveSpeed = 200
        theGameScene = gameScene

        //Call super initilizer
        super.init(texture: Ship.shipImage, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: Ship.shipImage.size())


        self.aGun = genericGun(gameScene: theGameScene, shipInstance: self)


        self.setScale(0.2)
        //Position is an property of SKSpriteNode so super must be called first
        self.position = startPos

        //Physics of the ship
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0//PhysicsCategory.Ship
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ship
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = CGFloat(0)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false //TBD

        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = controllerVector.dx * moveSpeed
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = controllerVector.dy * moveSpeed 
    }

    func updateVelocity(v:CGVector){

        if(v == CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)){
            self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
        }
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = v.dx * moveSpeed
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = v.dy * moveSpeed
    }

    func updateLaserPos(){
        //            laser.position = self.position
    }

    func updateShipProperties(shipVelocity v:CGVector,laserStartPos laserStart:CGPoint){
        updateVelocity(v)
        updateLaserPos()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }  
}
```

And this is where the ship would be instantiated:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var aShip = Ship(gameScene:GameScene(), startPosition: CGPoint(x:50,y:200),controllerVector: controlVector)
```

Comment: just assign your aGun to nil,  it needs some kind of initialization,  nothing and nil are indeed 2 different things

Comment: @knight0fDragon Is that what setting it to an optional sort of does as well? Also, if I try to add one of these gun objects (or bullet object) to the scene (assuming it was a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`) then would you suggest passing in `GameScene` to the class? Or is there a better way to go about it? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: "and since I don't really understand optionals" Then I suggest you stop and understand them before you go on. You really can't write a single intelligent line of Swift until you do.

Comment: @matt I grasp the basic premise but not enough to know why they're so powerful I guess. Any suggestions on how to learn about them besides the Docs (which I've already gone over for a while)?

Comment: You can do !(unwrapped optional) also and assign it to nil, so that the system knows that it can't be nil when reading it.  Before an initializing can happen,  default values need to be present in all variables, `var aGun : genericGun` has no default value. Now the way you have structured seems to be your problem,  Why would you be passing in ship into your gun?  do guns know about ship?  When you buy a gun from a store, does it to know everything about you? Design your gun to be a child of ship, then you can do `let aGun : genericGun` without it being an optional, and assign aGun before super

Comment: @Sam well, modesty prevents me. Okay, no it doesn't: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional

Comment: @Sam Also you don't seem to understand the rules of object initialization: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_initializers

Comment: Basically, you want to create a gun object that has no bearing on what a ship is,  then when the ship obtains the gun, the ship configures the gun.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I passed ship in so I could access all of its properties from gun. Gun has a method `shoot()` that creates an instance of a class `laser` which is a `SKSpriteNode` to be drawn to screen. For this reason, I thought it made sense to pass in the attributes laser needed about the ship, like where to start from ect. But you're saying it makes more sense to flip that order? Also any idea how I could use addChild(theLaser) within that method of `genericGun`? It would seem that I need `GameScene`, but when I pass it as an argument `GameScene()`, in the GameScene class, it doesn't work.

Comment: you make them class members of `SKNode` or `SKSpriteNode`,  then you can  add them as children.  Laser should be considered a bullet.  Do bullets know what gun it is in?  If you apply the way you program to the way you do things in life,  you will find your coding to be a lot eaiser. We have bullets who are `SKSpriteNode` that get loaded into a gun,  so you self.addChild(bullet) inside gun,  gun gets held by ship,  so you self.addChild(gun) inside ship.  Now ship.gun.shoots() will fire a gun,  inside the gun shoot method, gun tells a bullet to move

Comment: @knight0fDragon That makes sense, as of now I'm storing each instance of laser in an array property of Gun. (Each laser is initilized at `aShip`'s location, so that it fires from the ship itself). I don't fully understand where addChild would go inside the class, but I do get the logic of the shoot method. Is there anyway I could PM you the classes I built so that you could see what I'm talking about exactly and possibly offer advice? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: you should be able to start a chat here,  now with the addchild method,  you would be working in relative coordinates not absolute.  If you do not understand addChild, then how do you plan on drawing the laser?

Comment: @knight0fDragon I don't see where I can start one- maybe I need higher reputation? Also, I understand that I need to add a Sprite to the `GameScene` with `addChild` in order to draw it, but I don't think I fully follow using `addChild` to the class, how would I access it after? Also wouldn't it be an instance that I would be adding? So it would make sense to have the array for the various lasers? I can possibly update this post to include all the classes if that makes sense?

Comment: you can assign reference variables to the instances you make, or you can just look at the sprite children for the instance you need,  the method depends on the need

Comment: you do not need to add child only to the scene,  the scene is just the big daddy,  if you add to a node,  the object sticks with the node, but gets drawn by the scene.  Example:  Your body is the scene,  you add a shirt,  shirt is child of scene,  you draw a picture on your shirt, picture is child of shirt,  You still see the drawing.  You remove the shirt,  the picture goes with shirt,  so your body does not have the drawing anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118575/discussion-between-sam-and-knight0fdragon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing your game in a way that a `Ship` needs a `Gun` to be created and a `Gun` needs a `Ship` before the initialisation you are going into a lot of trouble.

> SpriteKit already solved this kind of problem with the `scene` property available in `SKNode`. It returns the `scene` the current node belongs to.

You could do something similar and make your life a lot easier

### Ship

```
class Ship: SKSpriteNode {
    lazy var gun: Gun? = { return self.children.flatMap { $0 as? Gun }.first }()
}
```

As you can see I created a lazy property, when you invoke the `gun` property of a `Ship` it automatically gets populated with the first `Gun` found among its children.

### Gun

You can do the same with the `Gun` object, as you can see it has a lazy var `ship` that gets populated with its parent conditionally casted to `Ship`.

```
class Gun: SKSpriteNode {
    lazy var ship: Ship? = { return self.parent as? Ship }()
}
```

### Test

```
let gun = Gun()
let ship = Ship()
ship.name = "Enteprise"
ship.addChild(gun)

print(gun.ship?.name) // Optional("Enterprise")
```

### Considerations

Following what SpriteKit did with the `scene` property, I made the properties `gun` and `ship` optionals. It means that if a `Gun` is not direct child of a `Ship` then its `ship` property will return `nil`.

Similarly if a `Ship` doesn't have a `Gun` among its children, then its `gun` property will return `nil`.

### Performance

Since the `ship` and `gun` property are `lazy` they will need a very small amount of time (the first time they are read) to be populated. You will not notice the delay but just keep it in mind.

### Using computed properties

Instead of making `ship` and `gun` lazy properties, you can defined them as computed properties. In this case if you move a Gun from a Ship to another you'll get consistent results.

On the other hand in this case each time you read `ship` and `gun` you'll need to way a very (very very very) little amount of time.

```
class Ship: SKSpriteNode {
    var gun: Gun? { return self.children.flatMap { $0 as? Gun }.first }
}

class Gun: SKSpriteNode {
    var ship: Ship? { return self.parent as? Ship }
}
```